# NoReverseMatch in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django

Here is my **url.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from app import views, auth
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name = 'index'),
    url(r'^login/', auth.login, name = 'login'),
    url(r'^logout/', auth.logout, name = 'logout'),
]
```

When I'm using in template `<li><a href="{% url 'admin' %}">Administration</a></li>` get error

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'admin' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

So can any one tell me how to solve this? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is this in your app folder? What about your project folder?

Comment: yes it is in my app folder

Comment: Set it in your project folder. Create a urls.py in the same folder where your settings.py is, then add 'url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),' and to call it use '<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">blablabla</a>'

Comment: Thanks @almostabeginner Please make it comment I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use admin namespace, like written in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls). You could also look on other admin urls in that namespace.

```
{% url 'admin:index' %}
```

Comment: Checking. One second

Comment: You're missing quotes around the url name: `{% url 'admin:index' %}`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `admin:index` if you want to have an url to `/admin/` site.
If you install [django-extensions](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-extensions/0.7.1) you can use `./manage.py show_urls` to get the list of urls for your app

Answer (score 1):

Set admin url in your project urls.py, same folder as your settings.py

```
Url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Then call it in your template:

`<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %} > link </a>`